# how to handle exception for promise in loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I am downloading files with zip folder, but it download the zip folder prior to add files in the zip folder object. If I remove them and catch block from call of "this. UrlToPromise ()" it works right, but when it faced reject from "this. UrlToPromise ()" it does not work correctly.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip = this.makezip(files, zip);
zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
    if (downloadName) {
        console.log('zip download one', zip);
        FileSaver.saveAs(content, downloadName + '.zip');
    } else {
        FileSaver.saveAs(content, 'All.zip');
    }
});

async makezip(files, zip, folderName = null) {
    if (folderName)
        var tempFolder = zip.folder(folderName);
    for (var i in files) {
        files[i].hasOwnProperty('file_title')
        if (!Array.isArray(files[i])) {
            if (typeof files[i]['file_title'] !== 'undefined' && typeof files[i]['file_path'] !== 'undefined') { 
                await this.urlToPromise(files[i]['file_path']).then(response=>{
                    if (!folderName)
                        zip.file(files[i]['file_title'] + '.' + returnExtFromImage(files[i]['file_path']), response, { base64: true, binary: true });
                    else
                        tempFolder.file(files[i]['file_title'] + '.' + returnExtFromImage(files[i]['file_path']), response, { base64: true, binary: true });    
                })
            }
        } else if (Array.isArray(files[i])) {
            zip = this.makezip(files[i], zip, i);
        }
    }
    return zip;
}

urlToPromise(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The exception handling isn't really the problem, but rather that you're not waiting for any of the promises in that loop.

Comment: yes you are right that is the problem but i have applied different code but didn't work can you share sample code please.

Comment: What codes did you try? An asynchronous loop generally needs either an `await` or `Promise.all`.

Comment: i have update the code by using awaita and async now it generate an error "zip.generateAsync is not a function"

Comment: `makezip` is now returning a promise

Comment: yes makezip is now returning a promise

Comment: what should i do to get rid of returning a promise in this case

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't) get rid of the promise. You just need to wait for it (with `await` or `.then`) as usual.

Comment: i am doing with await and .then

Comment: Thanks i have figure out my problem please see below answer and or suggestion for better solution

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use reject in a Promise constructor it will trigger the catch method of the Promise instance. Therefore, you need to add a catch handler when you call urlToPromise, like this:

```js
this.urlToPromise(files[i]['file_path']).then(response=>{
    if (!folderName)
        zip.file(files[i]['file_title'] + '.' + returnExtFromImage(files[i]['file_path']), response, { base64: true, binary: true });
    else
        tempFolder.file(files[i]['file_title'] + '.' + returnExtFromImage(files[i]['file_path']), response, { base64: true, binary: true });    
}).catch(error => {
    // do something with the error
})
```

Comment: same issue still it download prior

Comment: Thanks i have figure out my problem please see below answer and or suggestion for better solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `await` inside `async` function instead of `then/catch`. You can use `try catch` statement to catch the error.

```js
async makezip(files, zip, folderName = null) {
  if (folderName) var tempFolder = zip.folder(folderName);
  for (var i in files) {
    files[i].hasOwnProperty('file_title');
    if (!Array.isArray(files[i])) {
      if (
        typeof files[i]['file_title'] !== 'undefined' &&
        typeof files[i]['file_path'] !== 'undefined'
      ) {
        try {
          const response = await this.urlToPromise(files[i]['file_path']);
          if (!folderName)
            zip.file(
              files[i]['file_title'] +
                '.' +
                returnExtFromImage(files[i]['file_path']),
              response,
              { base64: true, binary: true }
            );
          else
            tempFolder.file(
              files[i]['file_title'] +
                '.' +
                returnExtFromImage(files[i]['file_path']),
              response,
              { base64: true, binary: true }
            );
        } catch (error) {
          // handle error
        }
      }
    } else if (Array.isArray(files[i])) {
      zip = this.makezip(files[i], zip, i);
    }
  }
  return zip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question i was missing await for recursive function.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
await this.makezip(files, zip).then(zip=>{
    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
        if (downloadName) {
            FileSaver.saveAs(content, downloadName + '.zip');
        } else {
            FileSaver.saveAs(content, 'All.zip');
        }
    });
});

async makezip(files, zip, folderName = null) {
    /*if folder name exist in props to create new nested folders*/
    if (folderName)
        var tempFolder = zip.folder(folderName);
    
    for (var i in files) {
        files[i].hasOwnProperty('file_title')
        if (!Array.isArray(files[i])) {
            if (typeof files[i]['file_title'] !== 'undefined' && typeof files[i]['file_path'] !== 'undefined') { 
                await this.urlToPromise(files[i]['file_path']).then(response=>{
                    if (!folderName)
                        zip.file(files[i]['file_title'] + '.' + returnExtFromImage(files[i]['file_path']), response, { base64: true, binary: true });
                    else
                        tempFolder.file(files[i]['file_title'] + '.' + returnExtFromImage(files[i]['file_path']), response, { base64: true, binary: true });

                }).catch(err=>{

                });
            }
        }
        else if (Array.isArray(files[i])) {
            /*recursive loop for nested folders files*/
            await this.makezip(files[i], zip, i);
        }
    }
    return zip;
}


async urlToPromise(url) {
    return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That usage of Promise helps you.

```
function sureify<T, U = Error>(promise: Promise<T>) {
  return promise
    .then((data) => [data, undefined] as [data: T, error: undefined])
    .catch((error: U | undefined) =>
      Promise.resolve([undefined, error] as [data: undefined, error: U])
    );
}
// Convert from Promise
const [response, error] = await sureify(urlToPromise("url"))
```